# RDLC report TextBox shifts if adjacent TextBox is not visible (I.E. Hidden)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, report, rdlc

I am using Visual Studio 2012 C# to create reports using the RDLC framework.  My report contains columns of TextBoxes fields.  Under certain conditions I need to hide the 2nd to last column.  When I do this (set hidden property to True) the far right column for those rows with a hidden row slides over to the left rather than being aligned with others in that column.  I am not using any properties that I can tell that would cause this.  My current workaround is to make the text color for the column to hide White, but this is really a hack in my opinion and won't work if the back color is to change.  Does anybody have any thoughts on how I can do this the right way, I.E. using a formula on the Hidden property of the TextBox rather than on the Color one?

Any help regarding this would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to define an expression for the `Value` of the TextbBox that prints nothing when the condition is met.

```
=Iif(YourCondition = True, "", Fields!YourColumn.Value)
```

Comment: Wouldn't that still leave the textbox as a whole, still taking up space? I think the goal is to determine visibility of the textbox as a whole

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what was asked. You should read the question again. The OP wishes to hide the value without having everything shift. The Op was able to hide the actual textbox, which is causing him trouble. His current solution was the change the font color, so I offered him a better alternative.